# Getting a YoY percentage from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe that has columns 'count', 'w', 'c', 'd' and 'y'
and sample data looks like this:

```
131    1    dir    mob    2017
244    1    dir    mob    2018
311    1    org    mob    2017
332    1    org    mob    2018
212    2    dir    dsk    2017
311    2    dir    dsk    2018
401    2    org    mob    2017
283    2    org    mob    2018
```

What is the way to get the percentage change of the 'count' value grouped by 'w','c','d'  for 2018 versus 2017?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 5):

Well you could sort your data (as you already have) and then calculate the diff as the difference between count and count.shift().

That difference we assign to the dataframe where we drop all the duplicated rows and cols we are not interested in:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
count  w      c      d       y
131    1    dir    mob    2017
244    1    dir    mob    2018
311    1    org    mob    2017
332    1    org    mob    2018
212    2    dir    dsk    2017
311    2    dir    dsk    2018
401    2    org    mob    2017
283    2    org    mob    2018'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.sort_values(by=['w','c','d','y'], inplace=True) # <--- sort values 

diff = (df['count'].shift(-1) - df['count'])/df['count'][::2] # <--- calculate % change

dfnew = df.drop_duplicates(('w','c','d')).drop(['y','count'],axis=1).assign(diff=diff)

print(dfnew)
```

Returns:

```
   w    c    d      diff
0  1  dir  mob  0.862595
2  1  org  mob  0.067524
4  2  dir  dsk  0.466981
6  2  org  mob -0.294264
```

---

You can add this verifier to check that you got the amount of correct columns:

```
sum(df[['w','c','d']].duplicated()) == len(df)/2  # <-- This should return True
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are 2 ways: the first (with `agg`) is faster than the second (`transform`), but for the sake of having options....

Nice thing is that they can deal with instances in which you have more than just 2 years to compare between

**Method 1**

You can sort your dataframe by `y`, then use `agg()` with [`pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df['pct'] = df.sort_values('y').groupby(['w', 'c', 'd']).agg({'count':'pct_change'})

>>> df
   count  w    c    d     y       pct
0    131  1  dir  mob  2017       NaN
1    244  1  dir  mob  2018  0.862595
2    311  1  org  mob  2017       NaN
3    332  1  org  mob  2018  0.067524
4    212  2  dir  dsk  2017       NaN
5    311  2  dir  dsk  2018  0.466981
6    401  2  org  mob  2017       NaN
7    283  2  org  mob  2018 -0.294264
```

**Method 2**

Similar, but using `transform()` instead of `agg`:

```
df['pct'] = df.sort_values('y').groupby(['w', 'c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: x.pct_change())['count']

>>> df
   count  w    c    d     y       pct
0    131  1  dir  mob  2017       NaN
1    244  1  dir  mob  2018  0.862595
2    311  1  org  mob  2017       NaN
3    332  1  org  mob  2018  0.067524
4    212  2  dir  dsk  2017       NaN
5    311  2  dir  dsk  2018  0.466981
6    401  2  org  mob  2017       NaN
7    283  2  org  mob  2018 -0.294264
```

Comment: Yeah well this might be slightly better.

Comment: It depends on what the OP wants as output, your way is nice too !

Comment: It's just that my solution requires correct data or it fails. But yeah it is probably faster than a groupby. Thanks :)